# Velodyne HDL32E sends data, but velodyne_driver gets none

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have an HDL-32E velodyne sensor, but I can't get live data :-)

If I use a file with captured data, everything is just fine and there is no problem(actually the file contains data from the sensor I'm using) - but if I try to run the velodyne_driver with live data, I get a "Velodyne poll() timeout" warning.

I already checked the input.cc file and added a few outputs to the ROS_INFO_STREAM to check, if the driver is listening on the correct port - which it does.

My best guess is, that

> poll(fds, 1, POLL_TIMEOUT);

always returns 0, despite the fact, that there is data on Port 2368

Is this some fuerte or ubuntu 12.04 issue?

Update:

Being root doesn't help, but I noticed that there is a
bug in Ubuntu 12.04 - you can't use a workspace that is in /home/username

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36191/velodyne-hdl32e-sends-data,-but-velodyne_driver-gets-none/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-06-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-11**:
Is this a problem with putting a ROS workspace some place like `/home/username/ros`? That works for me. Maybe it should be a separate question, but I wonder exactly how you set up the workspace, and what failed.

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-06-11**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/36282/ros-as-root-common-bug-when-in/

There you are - seems to be a linux-related bug, not ros. Still seemed worth reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Network configuration seems to cause frequent problems getting data from the HDL-32E. The older 64E (which I have) is easier because it broadcasts the packets.

According to the [HDL-32E Manual](http://velodynelidar.com/lidar/products/manual/63-9113%20HDL-32E%20manual_Rev%20C_FEB2012%20web.pdf), page 11, the 32E only sends data to a specific static IP address, `192.168.3.255`.

Exactly how you configure your network depends on your system's network environment. For the simple case of connecting the device directly to an ethernet port, this has been reported to work:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0  192.168.3.255 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-12-28**:
I  have try this method, however, it doesn't work. Have you solved this problem? If solved, can you tell me the way?